# Entities colors in the CodeFluent Entities Modeler

Tags: codefluent

How can I change the color of an entity in the CodeFluent Entities Modeler?

Current blue color isn't so good for a print-out.

Regards,
SF

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own style in the options menu:

[image: Options]

Click the "Create New" button and set the colors as you want.
Or select one of the 3 out-of-the-box themes.